# Inserting record to MySqlDb with entity framework5

Tags: mysql, frameworks, entity

Hi I'm trying to run Entity Framework 5 with MySql DB.
I have tried amount of MySql connectors 6.6.5,6.7.3,6.5.4 but i still getting exception while inserting items .
After tracing SQL command i have found that while SaveChanges, following command have been sent to MySQL DB

INSERT INTO (SELECT
      `test`.`TestField`
      FROM `test` AS `test`)(
`TestField`) VALUES (
10)}

As you can see I have here problem since instead of select should be table name.
I'm fighting with this issue about 2 days.
I'll be very glad for your help.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is generating the query?